# application not running in sleep mode?

Tags: android

my code is running fine when phone not in sleep mode

i used broadcast receiver to call application when date going to be changed
the code is as follow

```
public class DateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("facebook_message", "Date Changed 1");

        intent=new Intent(context, project.runningservice.SendPost.class);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        try {
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
            Log.d("message", "Wait");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

}
```

and code in manifest file is as follow

```
.
.
<receiver android:name="project.datereceiver.DateReceiver"
                  android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
.
.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
.
.
```

and i want my service class run at 8am everyday when date changed
but not working correctly when phone in sleep mode.
please tell me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Get rid of `DateReceiver` entirely (class and manifest entry).

Step #2: Modify your `AlarmManager`-related code to use `setRepeating()` instead of `set()` (and using a `Calendar` that is in the future, as yours is about ~45% likely to create a date in the past), and call that code when your app is first run and on reboots.

Comment: thank this is working but does it affects battery backup or not?
also i want application run at exactly 8am in the morning every day.so hows this possible.plz tell me.

Comment: @PrathameshTalathi: "but does it affects battery backup or not?" -- what is "battery backup"? "also i want application run at exactly 8am in the morning every day" -- follow the instructions in the answer that I supplied.

Comment: i follow all steps but i want start repeating task be started at 8am in the morning for first time.

Comment: @PrathameshTalathi: Create a `Calendar` object for today at 8am (if it is before 8am) or tomorrow at 8am (if it is after 8am right now). Use that with `RTC_WAKEUP` in your `setRepeating()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.currentTimeMillis().set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR*13,pi);
```